# Bar JFree Charts y-axis

Tags: jfreechart

I want to display Bar chart using jfree charts. I am able to display string data on y-axis
like A 0,B 100 on y-axis but the bars are displaying long.the bars are not displaying in proper format.
how to encode  y-values as integers in my dataset while still i have to display string data displayed above in that format?

Comment: Its very hard to help without some more information or a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) showing your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `SymbolAxis` needs a for each of the numberic values so you will need to provide 101 values (0 - 100) rather then the 11 in your code

Try replacing

```java
SymbolAxis rangeAxis=new SymbolAxis("", new String[] {"Poor    0", "10","20", "30", "40", "Avg.     50","60","70","80","90","Best   100"});
plot.setRangeAxis(rangeAxis);
```

with

```java
//Provide a new Symbol Axis
String[] grade =  new String[101];
for (int i = 0 ; i < grade.length ; i ++){
    grade[i] = Integer.toString(i);
}
grade[0] = "Poor    0";
grade[100] = "Best   100";
grade[50] = "Avg.   50";
SymbolAxis rangeAxis = new SymbolAxis("", grade);
rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10));
rangeAxis.setAutoRange(false);
rangeAxis.setRange(0, 100);
plot.setRangeAxis(rangeAxis);
```

Use  `SymbolAxis#setTickUnit()` to control the interval between tick marks and you shold get a chart line this

[image]

Comment: hi, i wanted one more clarification. The code u sent shows string values only at tick values counts. But if i have to Show string values in between the interval of tick values, how should i proceed?

Comment: If the answer given by @GrahamA solves your problem then you should accept it so that others who would be redirected to this page by search could use this solution as well.